# Pass information from html form to python flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am new to flask and web applications, trying to create a web application that takes the name and the sport for each user and store it in sqlite DB, now Iam trying to remove users from the DB by taking the registrant id from the html to flask.

flask:

```
@app.route("/deregister")
def deregister():
    value_from_html = ?????
    db.excute("DELETE * FROM registrant WHERE id = ?", value_from_html)
```

html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

        <h1>Registrant name</h1>

<tbody>
         {% for registrant in registrants %}
                 <tr>
                 <td>{{ registrant.name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ registrant.sport }}</td>
                         <td>
                         <form action="/deregister" method="post">
                         <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ registrant.id }}"> !-- trying to pass registrant.id to flask --!
                         <input type="submit" value="Deregister">
                         </form>
                         </td>
                 </tr>
         {% endfor %}
</tbody>

{% endblock %}
```

python code is not complete yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can recieve the form data in the following way.

```
@app.route("/deregister", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def deregister():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.files:
                uploaded_file = request.files['filename']
                data = uploaded_file.stream.read()
```

In order to send a variable to flask, you dont need to use forms, you can easily do that in the following way,

```
@app.route("/deregister/<string:id>", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def deregister(id):
    try:
        variable = id
        print(variable)
```

In html, keep this,

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

        <h1>Registrant name</h1>

<tbody>
         {% for registrant in registrants %}
                 <tr>
                 <td>{{ registrant.name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ registrant.sport }}</td>
                         <td>
                         <a href='/deregister/{{ registration.id }}'>Send Id</a>
                         </td>
                 </tr>
         {% endfor %}
</tbody>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve it my self finaly Ive found a way to do that:

1)Add button in my html to remove from DB:
[image]

[image]

I hope that this will help any one as it did for me.